# Negate characters in [A-zÀ-ÿ\d_] regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex expression which should accept any character including the underscore character. For this the following condition works just fine: [A-zÀ-ÿ\d_].

The probem here is that the following characters are also included: \ [ ] ^.

Is there a way to remove/negate them from the [A-zÀ-ÿ\d_] set?

Comment: Just fix as `[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ\d_]`

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the suplicated question :)

Comment: No need to be sorry, the `[A-z]` is so common an error, you can even find it in some online tutorials.